# Pressing a button on a web page using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have tried locating by class name but to no avail:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

button_locator = (By.CLASS_NAME, 'Text SmallTitle-module__smallTitle___aEy-i SellButton-module__buttonText___M7Q1y')
button = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(button_locator))
button.click()
```

HTML from the website:

```
<div class="SellButton-module__box___3D2et"><a rel="nofollow" data-cy="sell" href="/sell/for-sale" class="SellButton-module__link___Wyd2a SellButton" title="Sell" aria-label="Sell"><button class="Button-module__button___fE9iu Button-module__small___uF0cg Button-module__secondary___gYP5i SellButton-module__button___nsAPo" type="button"><p class="Text SmallTitle-module__smallTitle___aEy-i SellButton-module__buttonText___M7Q1y">Sell</p></button></a></div>
<a rel="nofollow" data-cy="sell" href="/sell/for-sale" class="SellButton-module__link___Wyd2a SellButton" title="Sell" aria-label="Sell"><button class="Button-module__button___fE9iu Button-module__small___uF0cg Button-module__secondary___gYP5i SellButton-module__button___nsAPo" type="button"><p class="Text SmallTitle-module__smallTitle___aEy-i SellButton-module__buttonText___M7Q1y">Sell</p></button></a>
<button class="Button-module__button___fE9iu Button-module__small___uF0cg Button-module__secondary___gYP5i SellButton-module__button___nsAPo" type="button"><p class="Text SmallTitle-module__smallTitle___aEy-i SellButton-module__buttonText___M7Q1y">Sell</p></button>
<p class="Text SmallTitle-module__smallTitle___aEy-i SellButton-module__buttonText___M7Q1y">Sell</p>
```

The element having both classes is not found, even though it's inside the HTML

Comment: What exactly is your problem here? What's not working?

Answer (score 0):

Getting an element that has many classes may sometimes not give you the element you expect.
For these cases what I do is to look inside that element that makes it unique. You could look to see if any of those classes repeat or are unique.
You could set up a CSS Selector or an XPath like this:

```
your_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//p[contains(@class, 'SmallTitle-module__smallTitle___aEy-i') and contains(text(), 'Sell')]")
```

So, here what you are doing is looking for the element with tag "p" that within its classes contains the class "'SmallTitle-module__smallTitle___aEy-i'" and also contains the text "Sell".
Please show what error you get or if it is ok.

Comment: Hi Nicolas, thanks for the response. From your code I am getting the error message: ```selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <p class="Text SmallTitle-module__smallTitle___aEy-i ...Button-module__buttonText___M7Q1y">Sell</p> is not clickable at point (1206, 41). Other element would receive the click: <div class="ReactModal__Overlay ReactModal__Overlay--after-open modal-overlay">...</div>```

Comment: What the error tells you is that when you click on that element it was intercepted by another one. You should check if there is something that is superimposed to that element.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you want to locate an element by class name, but you pass multiple class names. So you will need an alternative approach, possibly searching by CSS selector:

```
button_locator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.Text.SmallTitle-module__smallTitle___aEy-i SellButton-module__buttonText___M7Q1y')
```

Here the `.` means "class" and we are searching for elements having all the classes.